# Windows, how to run a command that would self execute a file every 10 seconds for a duration and append all output to a log file

Tags: windows, batch, prompt

I need a batch script or a one liner to run an executable and append its output from console to a text file

I also need this to run in a loop and dump the output every 10 seconds for a duration of 10 minutes, so 60 times. Each time the output should be appended to the end of the text file, so that it stores previous outputs

Lets say the executable is called "C:\monitor.exe"

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a `for /L` 60 times executing and `for /f` loop with `timeout 10` seconds:

```bat
rem :: for command line :: 
for /L %L in (1 1 60)do start "" /b "cmd /c "C:\monitor.exe" >>"%temp%\file.log" && for /f %i in ('timeout 10 /nobreak 2^>nul')do taskkill /f /t /im "monitor.exe"

rem :: for bat/cmd file :: 
for /L %%L in (1 1 60)do start "" /b "cmd /c "C:\monitor.exe" >>"%temp%\file.log" && for /f %%i in ('timeout 10 /nobreak 2^>nul')do taskkill /f /t /im "monitor.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks, I dont know why people downvoted this without comments!

Comment: @MiPo Good to know that work for you! Thank you.